# Left Join with two tables not Working

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to join  two two tables in MS ACCESS2010 query but it gives an error
Here is the query

```
SELECT f.FileName, f.CreationDate, fs.SheetName, fs.SheetNo, SB.Tags
 FROM Files AS  f  LEFT JOIN FilesSheets AS  fs
ON f.FileId = fs.FileId
LEFT JOIN SubmitSheets AS  SB 
ON  f.FileId =SB.FileId
WHERE f.FileId = 'Machine_Inspection_20140820183554.xlsx'
```

Here is the error

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Access Needs Parenthesis around joins to group them.  Try this:

```
SELECT f.FileName, f.CreationDate, fs.SheetName, fs.SheetNo, SB.Tags
FROM (Files f 
LEFT JOIN FilesSheets fs
ON f.FileId = fs.FileId)
LEFT JOIN SubmitSheets SB 
ON  f.FileId = SB.FileId
WHERE f.FileId = 'Machine_Inspection_20140820183554.xlsx'
```